# Remove horizantal scroll bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a mock hotel website and I added a carousel to my page to show pictures of different places. I want the pictures to fit the whole page under the navbar. however I got a horizontal scroll bar when i created a Ratings panel. What can I do to remove it?

The panel is under `<!--- Panel -->` comment
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BogMKq

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use overflow-x: hidden

Answer (score 2):

The page is missing a wrapping `.container`.

Add a wrapping div with class `container` and adjust its `max-width`.

Comment: Yes!! Infact, everything is cause by div.row in #main-carousel

Answer (score 1):

That is caused by the fact that the `.row` has negative margin. If you wrap that div inside a `.container-fluid` the horizontal scroll will disappear.

`.container-fluid` will keep the parent element's full width, `.container` instead has a max width which changes with media queries.

For future uses I suggest to properly read the bootstrap documentation about its grid system =)

Answer (score 0):

```
#main-carousel { overflow: hidden; }
```

That should do the trick.